# Weird Sub-ring/field? question

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Let $R=\{\frac{n}{10^{k}} \mid (n,k) \in Z, k>-1\}$ which is the sub-ring of the Rational numbers ( assumed true)

Consider S a subset of R

$S= \{(3/10),(33/100),(333/100),...\}$

Show that this set has an upper bound in R.

Does it have a least upper bound in the rationals?

yes 1/3

Explanation:
Lim as n goes to infinity of $(10^{n-1} *3)/10^{n}$ = 1/3

$1/3 \in \Bbb Q$

Does it have a least upper bound in R?

No

Explanation:
cant take the limit of a subring at infinity.

Comment: Any time you have an increasing convergent sequence, the limit *is* the l.u.b.

Comment: "the subring" or **a** subring? And how is that set S *specifically* defined? Its elements don't seem to have a precise form...

Comment: i promise you i have no idea lol. this is form a  second year abstract algebra course both of the answers i just made up and have nothing todo with anything i have ever seen in the class ( just some weird ideas i got from calculus)

Comment: None of the three tags are appropriate.

Comment: The explanation does not explain much. (What is the limit of a subring?!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$R$ is the ring ${\Bbb Z}[\frac{1}{10}]$ of rationals with a terminating decimal expansion, and $S$ is the set
$$
\{0.3,0.33,0.333,\ldots\}=\{\frac{1-10^{-n}}{3}\mid n\in {\Bbb Z}_{>0}\}.
$$
$S$ clearly has least upper bound $\frac 13$ in $\Bbb Q$, but $\frac 13$ has a non-terminating decimal expansion, so it's not in $R$.  Since $R\subseteq \Bbb Q$, and since $\frac 13$ is the least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$, there can't be any upper bound of $S$ below $\frac 13$ in $R$.  Any upper bound $u\in R$ of $S$ (e.g., $0.334$, $0.3334$, etc.) must then exceed $\frac 13$.  However, there must now be some power $10^{-N}$ of $10$ which is less than $u-\frac 13$, so $u-10^{-N}$ is a smaller upper bound of $S$ in $R$.  Therefore, $S$ has no least upper bound in $R$.

Comment: how do you know that R cannot contain a non terminating decimal expansion?

Comment: By definition.  As defined above in the question, it contains only fractions with denominator a power of $10$.  Those all have terminating decimal expansions.

Comment: Hmm, why isn't infinity an integer?
there is certainly infinite integers?

Comment: No, there aren't.  There are all sorts of infinite quantities in mathematics, but none of them are integers,  according to the usual definition of an integer.

Comment: That's rather philosophy (or nonstandard analysis:)

Comment: sorry im not a math student  it seems logical to move from there being infinite of something to using infinite of them to make something lol. so when we do a limit we need to do the limit over the reals?

Comment: If you want to compute a limit, it's much more likely that it will exist over the reals, as they're a complete field (every nonempty set of reals with an upper bound has a least upper bound.)

Comment: @Faust7, we can agree there are infinite of something, but that's different from saying you can do arithmetic with them as if they're part of the integers. Look into transfinite numbers.

Comment: @Faust7: There are infinitely many integers. Each and every one of them is finite though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\displaystyle\frac{333..3}{999..9}=\frac13$, so we have that all elements of $S$ is $<1/3$. Moreover, its $n$th element is
$$s_n=\frac{10^n-1}{3\cdot 10^n}=\frac{1-\frac1{10^n}}{3}$$
which tends to $1/3$ as $n\to\infty$, so, as $s_n$ is increasing, uts limit is the least upper bound, within $\Bbb R$, and since $1/3\in\Bbb Q$, it's the l.u.b. also among the rationals.

Answer (score 1):

Given any upper bound in $\rm\,R,\:$ say $\rm\ \color{#0A0}{\dfrac{n}{k}}\, >\, \color{#C00}{\dfrac{1}3},\ $ a [mediant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_%28mathematics%29) yields a smaller upper bound in $\rm\,R,\,$ viz.

$$\rm mediant\left(\dfrac{7\ \color{#0A0}n  }{7\ \color{#0A0}{k}},\ \dfrac{\color{#C00}1\ k}{\color{#C00}3\ k}\right)\ =\ \dfrac{7n+k\ \ }{7k+3k}\ =\ \dfrac{7n+k}{10 k}\ \in R$$